# Python Pipeline Error When Used in Cross Validation

Tags: python, pipeline, cross-validation

I have a complex error that can't interpret and can't figure out.  Evidently my preprocessing pipeline works when fitting a model simplistically but fails when I attempt cross validation.  I can't deciper the error and don't understand the issue.  Please help.

## Preprocessing

I have created a pipeline that performs some pre-processing tasks on data.  It works. Includes some customer transformers. Here is the code.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin


class column_selector(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, columns: list):
        self.cols = columns

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.loc[:, self.cols]


class dummy_creator(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # stateless transformer
        return self

    def transform(self, X):

        X_categorical_scaled_df = pd.get_dummies(X)
        return X_categorical_scaled_df 


class DFStandardScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):

        self.ss = None


    def fit(self,X,y=None):

        self.ss = StandardScaler().fit(X)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):

        Xss = self.ss.transform(X)
        X_continuous_scaled_df = pd.DataFrame(Xss, index=X.index, columns=X.columns)
        return X_continuous_scaled_df


pipeline_categorical = Pipeline(steps = [
            ('column_selector', column_selector(categorical_features)),
            ('create_dummies', dummy_creator())
           ])


pipeline_continuous = Pipeline(steps = [
            ('column_selector', column_selector(numeric_features)),
            ('scaler',DFStandardScaler())
           ])

feature_union = FeatureUnion([('cat', pipeline_categorical),
                      ('cont', pipeline_continuous)])
```

If I `fit_transform` the the pipeline I get good results:

```
X_train_enc = feature_union.fit_transform(X_train)

X_train_enc

>>>array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        , ..., -0.05977797,
        -0.21011127, -0.24460191],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., -0.68765273,
        -0.00946558, -0.82457039],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        , ..., -1.06122696,
```

## Model Without Cross Validation

If I now make a pipeline with the above pre-processing pipeline and a model (in this case Linear Regression) I still get good results (just predictions shown below to indicated data properly pre-processed and model fit):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

pipe = make_pipeline(feature_union, LinearRegression())

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
pipe.predict(X_validation)

>>>array([ 9.17773438,  9.38226318,  8.35693359, 10.62176514, 11.29095459,
        7.45025635,  6.03497314, 10.04321289, 10.57568359,  9.86663818,
        7.01202393,  8.08374023,  8.80700684, 10.80102539, 12.32678223,
        6.7588501 , 10.44604492,  6.86547852,  9.20465088,  9.04406738,
```

## Model With Cross Validation

Now I attempt to test the same model using cross validation.  You will note that I put the pipeline into a list (`pipelines') and the cross-validation in a loop.  This is because I intend to create a list of pipelines similar to this with different models and loop through them but that is outside the scope of my issue (but just in case you are wondering why I have coded it this way)

```
seed = 7     
pipelines = []
pipelines.append(('ScaledLR',Pipeline([('Preprocess', feature_union),('LR', LinearRegression())])))

results=[]
names=[]
scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'

for name, model in pipelines:

    kfold=KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print("%s %f (%r)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std()))
```

And I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2655             try:
-> 2656                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2657             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-1aa4a50ac843> in <module>
     29 
     30     kfold=KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
---> 31     cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
     32     results.append(cv_results)
     33     names.append(name)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    400                                 fit_params=fit_params,
    401                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
--> 402                                 error_score=error_score)
    403     return cv_results['test_score']
    404 

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    238             return_times=True, return_estimator=return_estimator,
    239             error_score=error_score)
--> 240         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    241 
    242     zipped_scores = list(zip(*scores))

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    915             # remaining jobs.
    916             self._iterating = False
--> 917             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    918                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    919 

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, return_estimator, error_score)
    526             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    527         else:
--> 528             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    529 
    530     except Exception as e:

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    263             This estimator
    264         """
--> 265         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    266         if self._final_estimator is not None:
    267             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    228                 Xt, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    229                     cloned_transformer, Xt, y, None,
--> 230                     **fit_params_steps[name])
    231                 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    232                 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    340 
    341     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 342         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    343 
    344     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params)
    612 def _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params):
    613     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 614         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    615     else:
    616         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    791             delayed(_fit_transform_one)(trans, X, y, weight,
    792                                         **fit_params)
--> 793             for name, trans, weight in self._iter())
    794 
    795         if not result:

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    915             # remaining jobs.
    916             self._iterating = False
--> 917             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    918                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
    919 

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    757                 return False
    758             else:
--> 759                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    760                 return True
    761 

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    714         with self._lock:
    715             job_idx = len(self._jobs)
--> 716             job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    717             # A job can complete so quickly than its callback is
    718             # called before we get here, causing self._jobs to

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    180     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    181         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 182         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    183         if callback:
    184             callback(result)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    547         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    548         # arguments in memory
--> 549         self.results = batch()
    550 
    551     def get(self):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    223         with parallel_backend(self._backend, n_jobs=self._n_jobs):
    224             return [func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 225                     for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    226 
    227     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params)
    612 def _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params):
    613     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 614         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    615     else:
    616         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    296         """
    297         last_step = self._final_estimator
--> 298         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    299         if hasattr(last_step, 'fit_transform'):
    300             return last_step.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    228                 Xt, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    229                     cloned_transformer, Xt, y, None,
--> 230                     **fit_params_steps[name])
    231                 # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    232                 # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    340 
    341     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 342         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    343 
    344     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params)
    612 def _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, **fit_params):
    613     if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 614         res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    615     else:
    616         res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    463         else:
    464             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
--> 465             return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
    466 
    467 

<ipython-input-24-666c2228e73d> in transform(self, X, y)
     13 
     14     def transform(self, X, y=None):
---> 15         return X.loc[:, self.cols]
     16 
     17 

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1492             except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1493                 pass
-> 1494             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1495         else:
   1496             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    866     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
    867         try:
--> 868             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
    869         except IndexingError:
    870             pass

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_lowerdim(self, tup)
    986         for i, key in enumerate(tup):
    987             if is_label_like(key) or isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 988                 section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
    989 
    990                 # we have yielded a scalar ?

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1911         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1912         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1913         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1914 
   1915 

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    139             raise IndexingError('no slices here, handle elsewhere')
    140 
--> 141         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    142 
    143     def _get_loc(self, key, axis=None):

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3574 
   3575         if axis == 1:
-> 3576             return self[key]
   3577 
   3578         self._consolidate_inplace()

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2657             except KeyError:
-> 2658                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2659         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2660         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: None
```

The error appears to be located in the pre-processing featureunion - but I'm not sure exactly where or why. I believe it might be in the create_dummies class around the pd.get_dummies() function but not sure.

Can someone advise as to what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

I am aware this is an old question but it was among the first that popped up when I was challenged with the same problem (code working without cross-validation and failing with it).

The reason this fails is because the signature of your custom estimator `column_selector` does not match the attributes. From sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#instantiation) on developing estimators:

> In addition, every keyword argument accepted by __init__ should correspond to an attribute on the instance. Scikit-learn relies on this to find the relevant attributes to set on an estimator when doing model selection.

It should work fine if you change it to:

```
class column_selector(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, columns: list):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.loc[:, self.columns]
```

Comment: Did I miss something?  Your class 'column_selector' is the same as the one I provide above.  No?

Comment: I changed `self.cols` to `self.columns` in `__init__` and `transform`.

Answer (score 0):

After a day and a half of brain busting I created a work-around.

I removed the pre-processing feature union from the final pipeline that included the feature union and the model.  I run the feature union on the training set within each pipeline loop, and then invoke the model in cross_validation while feeding in the encoded/transformed variables.  Here is the code.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

seed = 7 

#prepare Models

pipelines = []

pipelines.append(('ScaledLR',Pipeline([('LR',LinearRegression())])))

#evaluate each model

results=[]
names=[]
scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'
for name, model in pipelines:

    X_train_enc = feature_union.fit_transform(X_train)
    y_train = Y_train.values

    kfold=KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, X_train_enc, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    print("%s %f (%r)" % (name, cv_results.mean(),cv_results.std()))
```

Of course I don't technically need the final pipeline that simply calls the model.  However I am keeping for now as this is work in progress and I might put some other steps in.